# How OpenCoverage coverage works - are classes without any tests counted?

Tags: opencover

I think I have a basic misunderstanding of the way OpenCover (or coverage in general) is working.

**I think that classes without any tests are not counted in the coverage, which is very strange.**

for example, if I have two classes (lets say of the same number of lines) and one is fully covered while the other has NO UT written, I expect to get 50% coverage, but I believe that I am getting 100%.
This doesn't make sense to me.

So I have 2-3 questions:

1. Should I expect classes without any UT to be counted in the coverage %?
2. If so, how can I troubleshoot my issue? (should I look for something in the report? what exactly? is it possible that OpenCover ignores those classes for another reason?)
3. If not, how does this make sense? if I start adding UT to a legacy project, the coverage will drop every time I add UT to a class that did not have one until now. there must be something that I am missing if this is the case.

Thank you for you help,
Roy.

Comment: What do your classes look like? What does the XML report from OpenCover look like? What is the command line you are using? I did respond to you Hangout yesterday by the way.

Comment: I finally got around to it,

Comment: It seems that the XML report is actually missing projects witout UT. let me explain: I have a huge project (a solution) that includes several projects, some have UT and some do not. I only see coverage for classes that have UT. I tried adding a reference to those projects to the test dll hoping that it will provide this information to OpenCover, and I also tried adding an inclusion filter to the missing binaries without success. am I doing something wrong, or is this the way OpenCover supposed to work? is there a way to add to the coverage binaries that do not have UT (with 0 coverage)? Thank!

Comment: I suspect the assembly is not loaded and so it (and all the classes within it) are not seen by OpenCover. Adding an assembly reference will not necessarily cause an assembly to be loaded or even referenced if you do not use any of the types within it (compiler optimisations). Simplest way is to add tests for at least one type in each assembly you wish to get coverage for.

Comment: Thank you! this worked. I will think of how to do this automatically somehow (to test it I called Assembly.LoadFile(dll)). do you think it is something that is possible for the tool to do in later versions? it really seems strange to me that it is such an obscure issue, I would assume that legacy projects would require this since most of them do not have UT written to begin with.  anyway, thanks a lot for your help, and do you want to write it as an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: OpenCover does not load assemblies ad-hoc as it does not know which ones it should be loading unless the runtime specifically requested  them - this is by design. Since adding a test resolves the issue for the user it is better to keep it that way rather than 2nd guess what should be loaded and what should not be loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the assembly is not loaded and so it (and all the classes within it) are not seen by OpenCover.

Simplest way is to add tests for at least one type in each assembly you wish to get coverage for.